# How to define a static constexpr 2D array in a C++ class template?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, templates

I have a class template which accepts another class template and an `int` as the template parameters. I would like to create one, shared two-dimensional array which will be accessible to all class instances as well as `static public` methods (so that its not bound to any specific instance, but the `class`). I would like the array to be initialised at compile time. I cannot really nail it down; I have been trying various options but always end up with an error...

Example:

```cpp
template <const unsigned int x, const unsigned int dim>
class Class1<Class2<x>, dim> {
 private:
    static constexpr int multable[dim][dim] = initializeMultable();
 public:
    static constexpr const int(*initializeMultable())[dim] {
        static int result[dim][dim];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < dim; ++j) {
                result[i][j] = i + j // whatever
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

What is the proper way to initialise such an array at compile time?

### This question is still open, as I mentioned in the comments the answer below does not compile.

Comment: `result` cannot be `static`.

Comment: Not sure if it may help you, but have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75429273/7143595)

Answer (score 2):

C arrays can't be returned from functions. Use `std::array` instead:

```
template <const unsigned int x, const unsigned int dim>
class Class1<Class2<x>, dim> {
 private:
    static constexpr auto multable = []{
        std::array<int[dim], dim> result{};
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < dim; ++j) {
                result[i][j] = i + j // whatever
            }
        }
        return result;
    }();

 public:
    static constexpr auto initializeMultable() {
        return multable;
    }
};
```

Comment: The local variable shouldn't be declared `static`.  `constexpr` code can modify variables whose lifetime is bounded by the constexpr call, but is not allowed to have any side effects which survive past the end of the function call.

Comment: See https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.2 and https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.16

Comment: @Artyer: Does not work, I get:
`error: use of undeclared identifier 'initializeMultable'
  static constexpr auto multable = initializeMultable();`

Comment: I don't think I can place it at the end since my class has more `private` variables, used by regular class methods

Comment: @maciek Previous errors were because I had just copied your question's code replacing the array with `std::array`, but this still runs into issues because [you simply can't initialize a `static constexpr` data member by calling a `static constexpr` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11522399). Replaced it with a lambda, and your old public `initializeMultable` function can just copy the static data member.

Comment: @Artyer : Unfortunately, this is still bugged: `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::array<int [4], 4>'` at: `std::array<int[dim], dim> result{};`.

Comment: The above problem was solved with `#include <array>`
However, the code still does not work, I get: `error: constexpr variable 'multable' must be initialized by a constant expression` at `static constexpr auto multable = []{`